# combine several columns into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I combine these columns:

```
id|clock_in |clock_out|lunch_out|lunch_in
1 | 8:00    | 5:10    | 1:00    | 1:50
2 | 8:02    | 5:45    | 1:02    | 1:55
```

into  this table:

```
id| activity  | time
1 | clock_in  | 8:00
1 | clock_out | 5:10
1 | lunch_out | 1:00
1 | lunch_in  | 1:55
2 | clock_in  | 8:02
2 | clock_out | 5:45
2 | lunch_out | 1:02
2 | lunch_in  | 1:55
```

Comment: Can you show us, or describe what you've already attempted?  Where's your actual table update command you've tried?  What was the error or issue you received?

Comment: I got no idea how to do it?

Comment: Great, show us what you've tried so far please.  Alternatively, please read [ask] for direction as to what we expect from a well-formed question.

Comment: create table new_employee as 

SELECT 
  employee.id, 
  employee.clock_in AND employee.clock_out AND employee.lunch_out AND employee.lunch_in FROM office.employee I got syntax error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your table create attempt.  It still seems like you should be reading [ask] as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple `union` with one sub-select for each column:

```
select id, 'clock_in' as activity, clock_in as time
from the_table
union all 
select id, 'clock_out' as activity, clock_out 
from the_table
union all
select id, 'lunch_out' as activity, lunch_out
from the_table
union all
select id, 'lunch_in' as activity, lunch_in
from the_table
order by id, 
      case activity
         when 'clock_in' then 1
         when 'clock_out' then 2
         when 'lunch_out' then 3
         when 'lunch_in' then 4
      end;
```

The `order by` resembles the order you have shown as your sample output is apparently is not ordered by the `time` column